# can we select specific columns with nettiers find() method

Tags: linq-to-entities, codesmith, .nettiers

I am using nettiers for one of my clients. I have noticed that when I call find() with search parameters, the execution gets time out. When I saw the query using profiler, it makes use of all the columns. i.e. select * from table.

Can we fetch specific columns using nettiers find() or any other way ?

Thanks ,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, .nettiers is trying to return a TList by default, so it needs all of the columns and it needs them in the expected order, since it uses column indexing in the DataReader rather than named column indexing.

If you want to build a specific tuned request use a custom stored procedure. My post below should help you:

http://benpowell.org/paging-and-sorting-in-a-nettiers-custom-stored-procedure/

Another alternative is to build a view. .Netiers will give you a VList back, so you can tune the columns down in the view definition.